# Query in json array/JObject

Tags: c#, json, linq

My json:

```
"CustomData": [
  {
    "Key": "RegistrationWrx",
    "Value": "Wrx45687",
    "Id": 462,
  },
  {
    "Key": "IsConsentGiven",
    "Value": "True",
    "Id": 463,
  },
```

I use this to get some values:

```
string fetchResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sidebar, Formatting.Indented);
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(fetchResult);

ConsentGiven = rss["RegistrationCase"]["CustomData"][1]["Value"].Value<string>(),
```

But i want to check the "Key" e.g. on "CustomData" and display the "Value". I think i need to do something like:

```
ConsentGiven = rss["RegistrationCase"]["CustomData"].Where(["Key"]=="IsConstantGiven")["Value"].Value<string>(),
```

Answer (score 2):

your question is getting a couple of marks down because it's a little vague.

But, i think I understand what you need...

The way I find easiest to parse json content is to convert it first.

so Create and class that matches your incoming json:

```
public class CustomData{
    public string Key {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set}
    public int? ID {get;set;}
}
```

then, in what ever method you use to read the json, instantiate and object of that type convert it.

```
public CustomData ConvertCustomDataJson(string jsonString)
{
List<CustomData> customData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomData>>(jsonString);
}
```

Then you can just use your object to loop through them easily, store them use them at will.

I've boshed this out quickly, so it might not be perfect.

Linq Query to find the value

```
bool value = Convert.ToBool(customData.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Key == "IsConsentGiven").Value);
```

Also, you'll need a reference to NewtonSoft json library. this is a nuget package in VS 2012

Martyn

Edit: here is a fully working version of what I mean, you could find the different entries by using indexes, but, and this might just be me, I get nervous because i never know if the json content may change.

serialising the object gives means it should cope with most changes the json or additional data, plus the benifit of being strongly typed just makes it easier to read.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LinqFun
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Set Data
            string jsonString = @"[
                                      {
                                        ""Key"": ""RegistrationWrx"",
                                        ""Value"": ""Wrx45687"",
                                        ""Id"": 462,
                                      },
                                      {
                                        ""Key"": ""IsConsentGiven"",
                                        ""Value"": ""True"",
                                        ""Id"": 463,
                                      }
                                   ]";

            //Create a list of CustomData entries to look through.
            List<CustomData> customData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomData>>(jsonString);


            //Create an object for the is consent given block of data

            CustomData IsConsentGiven = customData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "IsConsentGiven");

            //check the linq query resulted in an object
            if (IsConsentGiven != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(IsConsentGiven.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

     public class CustomData{
         public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public int? ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

you can pull the value of the IsConsentGiven straight out, but if you'd have to encompass it in a try block in case the data was missing, I prefer checking it myself.
the linq to directly pull it out though would be:

```
bool value = Convert.ToBoolean(customData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "IsConsentGiven").Value);
```

Comment: The thing i was looking for was a linq query. Not sure if it is possible but something like this: ConsentGiven = rss["RegistrationCase"]["CustomData"].Where(["Key"] == "IsConstantGiven")["Value"].Value<string>(),

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful,Create a class having the value property then do the bellow

```
  public class Category
{

   public string Value{ get; set; }

 }

 var categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(json)
```